# How to install repo for AEM?

Tags: java, maven-3, aem

I am trying to install this repo(https://github.com/sinnerschrader/aem-react) into AEM but getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-maven) on project aem-react: Some Enforcer       
rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
```

Also getting this warning:

[WARNING] Rule 1: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireJavaVersion failed with message:
Project must be compiled with Java 8 or
                    higher

When I check the javaversion I get :

```
java version "1.7.0_79"                                            
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)               
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

Bit confused now which version of java to install because it says 1.7.0_79?

Answer (score 1):

It definitely says in the github docs

> >= Java 8 (Oracle JDK with nashorn engine)

github -> https://github.com/sinnerschrader/aem-react#dependencies

so you just need to install newer Java version. it's all there in the documentation!

java 8 -> https://www.google.com/search?q=java+8+download

Answer (score 0):

You should use java 8 JDK, both the project you are compiling and AEM can run on it.

You can download it here

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html